# How to fix bootstrap nav bar overlap?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

having some issue with my bootstrap side nav.

Any content i try to add the page just overlaps on top of the Nav bar.

You can see it here -
http://35.197.236.48/#

What i want to happen is for the content to be to the right of the navbar.
I've tried adding rows/columns/containers and just can't get it work properly.

Can anyone see where I have gone wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js"></script>
  <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/c6d65aa6d0.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="generator" content="PSPad editor, www.pspad.com">
  <title>Tools</title>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- Nav bar, Using bootstrap -->
  <div class="nav-side-menu">
    <div class="brand">Brand Logo</div>
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>

    <div class="menu-list">

      <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">
        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-lg"></i> Dashboard
          </a>
        </li>

        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> UI Elements <span class="arrow"></span></a>
        </li>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">CSS3 Animation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">General</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Buttons</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Tabs & Accordions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Typography</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FontAwesome</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Slider</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Panels</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Widgets</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Bootstrap Model</a></li>
        </ul>


        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#service" class="collapsed">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-globe fa-lg"></i> Services <span class="arrow"></span></a>
        </li>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="service">
          <li>New Service 1</li>
          <li>New Service 2</li>
          <li>New Service 3</li>
        </ul>


        <li data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#new" class="collapsed">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-car fa-lg"></i> New <span class="arrow"></span></a>
        </li>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="new">
          <li>New New 1</li>
          <li>New New 2</li>
          <li>New New 3</li>
        </ul>


        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></i> Profile
          </a>
        </li>

        <li>
          <a href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></i> Users
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-one">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <div class="row" style="margin-top:5%;">

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-group features-box">
            <li class="list-group-item features-box text-center">
              <h4>Number of Hosts</h4>
              <span>.</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-group features-box">
            <li class="list-group-item features-box text-center">
              <h4>Hosts Online</h4>
              <span>.</span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <ul class="list-group features-box">
            <li class="list-group-item features-box text-center">
              <h4>Hosts Offline</h4>
              <span></span>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You'll have to add `.row-one { margin-left: 300px; }` because `fixed` elements are removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout

Comment: **You are in "quirks mode".** Your doctype is one that should not be used since 1999 at least! Change it to `<!DOCTYPE html>` to bring you into this century. However, this may change how your page looks cause you've been in quirks where one should never be!

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your side-bar is working, there is no overlap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add pull-right class to div.row-one, and give below css,

```
.row-one.pull-right {
    width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Comment: This works, but seems abit messy?  I'd of thought they'd be a way to do this without CSS'ing it, simply just by the way I had my divs or something.

Comment: @TheOne745665 as I mentionned in my comment, using `display: fixed`, 
 the element is removed from the document flow and will not be taking any space in the dom. You can use floats or bootstrap grid system instead and only overflow:scroll your right panel. Though, in this case, I don't think a calc is necessary and a simple margin makes more sense.